# Printing "\" character in C++

Tags: c++

This question may be silly but would be great if i understand the behavior.

I try to print

`\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\`

using a simple program

```
char testme [] ="\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\0";
cout<<"testme:"<<testme<<endl;
```

The out put in this case is

```
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
```

I intend to print 64 "\" characters, instead the output is 32 "\" characters.

There seems to be some thing that i am missing since the out put is exactly half.

Edit: The reason why i was asking is becasue , i have to `^`  "\" to another char for HMAC encryption and i see some weird things.

Comment: To print a \, \ should be escaped: `\\`.

Comment: That isn't even C. It's C++.

Comment: Didn't your instinct tell you to double that amount? (You got 32 instead of 64..)

Comment: @MarounMaroun Yes my instinct tells so.. i wanted to understand why..

Comment: The back slash is the escape character. As such, it will not be printed but is a signal to interpret the next character in a special manner. Thus to print a single back slash, you must back slash the back slash, if that makes sense. In other words, if you want to print a single back slash you must have two consecutive back slahes.

Comment: @Terry A backslash will be printed, and his code prints all of the backslashes in the string.  It's only in the actual source code (string literals and character constants, in particular) that the backslash is special.  (It's also special if it is immediately followed by a newline, but this is handled via a different mechanism, earlier in the translation than the backslashes in strings and character constants.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print a `\` standard states that

### C11; 6.4.4.4 Character constants:

> The double-quote `"` and question-mark `?` are representable either by themselves or by the
>   escape sequences `\"` and `\?`, respectively, but **the single-quote `'` and the backslash `\`
>   shall be represented, respectively, by the escape sequences `\'` and `\\`**<sub>1</sub>.

That mean to print a `\` you need an extra backslash `\` . To print two `\\` you need four backslash `\\\\` and hence for `64` backslash you need `128` backslash.

---

<sub>1. Emphasis is mine.</sub>

Comment: The escape sequences have nothing to do with printing, and to _print_ a \, it is sufficient to output a (single) \.  The escape sequences are only present in string and character literals.  (To output 64 1, I'd probably do something like `std::cout << std::string( 64, '\\' )`.  No way I'm going to count the characters in the source myself.)

Comment: @JamesKanze; My answer is for C. The C tag has been removed after my answer.

Comment: C and C++ are identical in this respect.  There is _nothing_ special about a backslash when outputting; it is output (printed) exactly like most other characters.  (A `'\n'` is treated special, at least if the output is text.)  The backslash is special _in the source code_, and in the source code only; in his case, in a string literal.  He doesn't print 64 backslashes, because he has created a string literal with only 32 backslashes.

Comment: Now that I think of it: C _does_ have an escape character in `printf`, et al.  The `%`, which indicates that what follows is to be interpreted differently.  So `printf( "%%" )` does print a single `%`, even though there are two in the string.

Comment: @JamesKanze; If it has nothing to do with it then how could you print a `\\` without using another `\\`?

Comment: Read it from a file.  In fact, write anything but a string literal (or a character literal).  The \ character is not special when printing, and any answer which says it is is simply incorrect.

Comment: Also, the section of the C standard you quote doesn't concern his code, since it describes character constants; there are no character constants in his code.  (String literals obey similar rules.)

Comment: @JamesKanze; Same for the backlash character. `printf("\\")` will print a single `\\``.

Comment: And... `printf( "\\" )` passes a string with a single \ to `printf`.  `printf( "%%" )` passes two % characters to `printf`.  Try reading the format string from a file (which is the usual situation; it's fairly rare in well written code for format strings to be string literals, since they vary from one language to the other).

Answer (score 8):

in C++11 you can do like this...

```
char testme [] =R"(\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\0)";
cout<<"testme:"<<testme<<endl;
```

The R"(...)" for `Raw Character Strings`...
To represent a backslash () in a string literal, we have to precede it with a backslash. To prevent errors (cos of too many backslash), C++ provides `raw string literals`...

Comment: In C++ (C++11 or not), you can do `std::string( 64, '\\' )`, and not have to count manually.  (Question: in his original, does the string end with two '\0', or with a character `'0'` followed by a `'\0'`?  I don't know, but in the first case, your string is not identical.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: I got that. I will edit my post to fit his answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is called escaping and is a mechanism to insert certain characters into a string. For example, if you want to insert a citation mark into a string, you need to escape it.

```
char testme [] ="I am a so called \"programmer\".";
```

There's also `\n`, `\t` and other codes. However, this applies to `\` itself, since you might want to be able to have a string that says `\n` without converting it into a newline character.

```
char testme [] ="This is a backslash followed by the letter n: \\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

`\\` is used to denote a single backslash: `\`. This is because `\` is used in string literals to denote other symbols like `\t` for a tab, `\n` for a newline and `\"` for a quotation character.

So `\\` gives you one backslash, `\\\\` gives you two and so on.

Answer (score 3):

`\` is a special character known as [Escape Character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C). For ex:: `\n` means `newline character`. So, if you want to print `single \`, you have to give `\\`. The first `\` says the compiler to not treat the next `\` as an escape character.

Comment: Wrong.  If you want to print a single \, you have to give it a single \.  The problem is that in string literals and character constants, `"\\"` represents a single \.

Comment: What sort of example?  Something as simple as `std::cin >> text; std::cout << text;` will do the trick.  Just enter a \ in the text.

Answer (score 3):

If it is C++, why not use string:

```
string testme(64, '\\');
cout << testme << endl;
```

Comment: This is, of course, the only sensible solution (even if you don't explain why his code doesn't work).

Answer (score 2):

The backslash `\` is a very widespread escape character, and C++ also uses it like that. This means it's used to express special meaning (usually nonprintable characters). For example, to encode a line-feed character (ASCII 10) into a string, you express it as `\n` in the string literal. Another example, putting a single backslash at the end of a line (that is, before the line's terminating newline character) escapes the newline - so this way, you can continue a macro definition or `//`-style comment across several source file lines, and they will still count as one logical line.

This of course means that to get a literal backslash character, you have to escape the backslash itself, to get remove its "escape character" status. So typing `\\` into a string literal yields a literal `\` character.

That's why you get only half the amount of backslashes output - the C++ source code parser consumes two to produce one.

Comment: Just a nit (since you are one of the few who answered correctly), but there are two distinct mechanisms in C and C++.  In the case of escaping a newline in the source, the rule is that a backslash preceding a newline will be removed (along with the newline).  So ending a line with `\\\` (not in a string literal or character constant) will leave two backslash, and not just one.  (Either way, of course, it's going to result in a compiler error, since the only place \ is legal is immediately before a newline, or in a string literal or character constant.)

Answer (score 2):

Didn't you notice one thing:

You printed 64 `'\'` but it printed only 32 of them.

Did you try 60, or 54, or some odd combi. say 33 ?

In C, `'\'` is escape character. You should have used `'\n'` for newline didn't you notice then, that `'\'` is not being printed.

To print `'\'` you must use `'\\'`.

A question for you:

Try printing 64 `'%'`. See what you get. Try understanding the reason for the output.

Comment: tx for your quick answer . Answring your question i get 64 "%"

Comment: @samairtimer : Try printing without first storing in an array. I mean `printf("%%%%...");`